# ADO.net update / add / delete Many to Many items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado

I'm attempting to add an image to a table and link it to a product. Here's the database table setup.

> ---- TWebProducts ----
>
> - intWebProductID
> - ... A bunch of other variables that don't matter here
>
> ---- TWebProductImages ----
>
> - intWebProductID
> - intWebImageID
>
> ---- TWebImages ----
>
> - intWebImageID
> - varImage

Here's what I'm attempting to do which, is not working.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProductEdit(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, TWebProduct tbl, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // Thumbnail image
            if (file != null)
            {
                string path = null;
                string pic = null;
                pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductThumbnails/"), pic);
                // file is uploaded
                file.SaveAs(path);
                tbl.varThumbnailImage = pic;
            }

            tbl.dteModified = DateTime.Now;
            tbl.intCompanyID = 1;

            // update the images
            
            string fName = "";

            try
            {
                //loop through all the files
                foreach (var img in files)
                {

                    //Save file content goes here
                    fName = img.FileName;
                    if (img != null && img.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        #region ImageSaving Stuff

                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}ProductImages\\", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                        //string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "imagepath");
                        string pathString = originalDirectory.ToString();

                        var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(img.FileName);

                        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);

                        if (!isExists)
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, img.FileName);
                        img.SaveAs(path);

                        #endregion


// this is the important part


                        // Get all the data saved to a variable
                        TWebImage webImage = new TWebImage();
                        webImage.varImage = path;


                        // Add to the TWebImages and link to the Product
                        tbl.TWebImages.Add(webImage);

                        
                    }

                }

                // Update the product
                _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<TWebProduct>().Update(tbl);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Products");
        }
```

There's no error, but there's nothing in the link table or the images table.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I'm new to using ADO Entity and repositories. I'm pretty well versed in SQL and C#.

I don't know what to google or even what to look for. Any and all help is appreciated. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: "There's no error" - well you've got an empty catch block in your code. That's a huge code smell and you should remove it.  An empty catch block in your code says "I don't care if this code works or not, don't even bother telling me if something goes wrong". At the very least you should log the exception.

Comment: I used a breakpoint to see if it threw an error or not.